# Is there a way to git cherry-pick without having to deal with tag pollution

Tags: git, github, github-for-mac

So cherry-pick is one of the best things since sliced bread but the fact that I have to see/deal with tags from the additional repo is no fun.

I have RepoA which is my repo and RepoB which is owned by someone else on github. Accordingly, I add RepoB to my .git/config with the following setup

```
[remote "repob"]
    url = git://github.com/foo/bar.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/repob/*
    fetch = +refs/tags/*:refs/tags/repob/*
    tagopt = --no-tags
```

I then do a "git fetch repob" before cherry-picking. The problem I have is that the git fetch will happily import all of repob's branches, tags etc. into my repo. Granted, it is in the repob namespace but I'm looking for a way to be able to just cherry-pick one reference from just that repo and be on my way while keeping my repo clean with just my tags and branches.

Answer (score 1):

Try `git fetch repob $interesting_ref --no-tags` then `git cherry-pick FETCH_HEAD` etc.